# No power through daisy chain

Tags: guitar-effects

I have a Boss BCB 30 pedal board with daisy chain. I have three pedals: TU2, CS3 and DD3. I bought an universal power supply to use with it. I have set the power supply to correct polarity and voltage. I've checked with a voltmeter and it shows 9.13 volt. It also work with each of the pedals, but not if all pedals are connect with daisy chain.

I have tested the daisy chain with my voltmeter to see if there is a connection, and there are. But if I test it with voltmeter when connect, it doesn't show any voltage.

TLDR: daisy chain doesn't deliver power, but wires are sound.

Comment: Is the "daisy chain" a separate cable that plugs into the power supply and then into all the pedals? If so that piece might be broken.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes, it's a separate cable that came with the [BCB 30 pedal board](http://www.soundaffectspremier.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Boss-BCB-30-Pedal-Board.jpg). I have tested the cable with a voltmeter, and it seems to have connection if I just tests each ends of cable (female plug to each of the male plug).

Comment: But if you plug it in, you don't see 9V at the outputs with the tester?

Comment: @ToddWilcox That's correct. Shows connection if I just test cable. Shows 0 if I test volt when plugged into power socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something's wrong with your daisy-chain cable. Likely the end the plugs into the power supply has the wrong plug and/or is not making contact with the power supply output.

Comment: May it be that I might need an original Boss adapter? This universal adapter I have fits perfectly into the daisy chain and I can change polarity to make it right, so I guess it should work?

Comment: The fact that it doesn't work is more significant than the supposition that it should work.

Comment: You answer made me double check the daisy chain. It seems like the pin inside the daisy chain is a bit smaller than the inside of the adapter plug. Making me guess that Boss has made their adapter plug a little bit different than the universal ones. Can I just put some alumnium foil inside the plug, or would it be a bad idea?

Comment: I can't imagine the correct cable costing that much. Using aluminum foil as a conductor is almost certainly a fire hazard.

Comment: Kinda needed a quick fix, but I'll wait for the original one. Thanks for helping out!